# C# Concatenate URL with 2 or more strings in between the url

Tags: c#, http, datetime, json-deserialization, getasync

trying to get a list of dates, I need to add 2 strings in between the URL

1. Cant concatenate the URL right
2. Need help deserializing into a DateTime list

   ```
   public async Task<List<DateTime>>GetDate()
   {
    // Original Url  http://local:8796550/serv/newobj/v678/object/35b724c5424/serv/addIDinhere/dates .    
       List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

       var Id= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxhola57a";
       var Uri = "http://local:8796550/serv/newobj/v678/object/35b724c5424/serv/";
       var Date="/dates";
       var client = new HttpClient();
       var ServicesDateRequest = await client.GetAsync($"{Uri}&={Id}&={Date}");
       string oj = await ServicesDateRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       //here deserialized it into datetime list 
       var DatesJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dates>(oj);

     return dates;

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) you only need the curly braces and the expression. The `"&="` that you're adding between each component is unnecessary to get to the url format you're looking for (assuming that the format you want is what the "Original Url" comment shows).

```
var ServicesDateRequest = await client.GetAsync($"{Uri}{Id}{Date}");
```

For deserialization, check out the documentation on the method you're using. Specifically, the part about Type Parameters. [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm).

> Type Parameters
>   T
>   The type of the object to deserialize to.

In other words, you should be using the type that you want to deserialize (in this case `List<DateTime>` rather than the name of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use string.format to format your url with query string paramteres.
Do Deserialize, you need to use type no data.

```
public async Task<List<DateTime>> GetDate()
    {
        // Original Url  http://local:8796550/serv/newobj/v678/object/35b724c5424/serv/addIDinhere/dates .    
        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
        var Id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxhola57a";
        var Date = "/dates";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var formatedUrl = string.Format("http://local:8796550/serv/newobj/v678/object/35b724c5424/serv/?id={0}&date={1}", Id, Date);
        var ServicesDateRequest = await client.GetAsync(formatedUrl);
        string oj = await ServicesDateRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //here deserialized it into datetime list 
        var DatesJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(oj);

        return DatesJson;

    }
```